# Which type to set for component Angular?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I tried to pass concrete component to dialog:

```
public open(dialogModel: IDialog, component: any): Observable<boolean> {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(component, {
      disableClose: true,
      panelClass: dialogModel.settings.cssClass,
      data: dialogModel.data
    });

    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
```

Which type to set for `component: any`? If it can be different component?

Comment: for components you want to use Type<any>..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as it can be:

```
component: FirstComponent | SecondComponent | ThridComponent;
```

Or

```
component: Type<any>;
```

See [Component](https://angular.io/api/core/Component)

Comment: What is it: `Type<any>`?

Comment: If you pass a component e.g. `AppComponent` the type of this component is `AppComponent`. Therefore if you want to pass components of different types you can simply say: All components where the `Type` is `any`.